# Odd Behavior with MembershipCreateStatus.Success

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm having some really odd behavior with some code that creates an ASP.Net user and then checks for success.  The problem is, it seems to run code in BOTH branches of the if else:

```
 if (result == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                    {
                        ErrorLog("MembershipCreateStatus.Success for user: " + Email.Text);
                        
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorLog("But also got here for non-successful creation of new user??? new user: " + Email.Text);
                        // No Success
                        lblPanel4.Text = GetErrorMessage(result) + " #2";
                    }
```

When I look at my log files they show both error messages:

```
MembershipCreateStatus.Success for user: man57@t.com 1/4/2021 8:13:59 PM
But also got here for non-successful creation of new user??? new user: man57@t.com 1/4/2021 8:14:00 PM
```

I've looked through the code and this method is getting called twice, wrapped into to different event handlers for two separate buttons.  Only one of them is being clicked on my page, so I can't see this as somehow running twice accidentally.

Comment: Well, it would be interesting to see your code. Otherwise, it's impossible to help.

Comment: @JuanR, I just changed the question because there's a more basic question regarding why the code is seemingly running both branches of an if/else statement.

Comment: That's a different story. Check to see how you are firing the click event. As described, this indicates that the event is being bound/fired  twice. It makes sense that the second execution of the code finds the user created a second ago and executes the `else` branch. It would help if you post a more complete code snippet. Please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example